# How do I run a regular global update in a Windows Store App with C#?

Tags: c#, networking, asynchronous, windows-store-apps

So, I'm trying to develop a Windows Store App extension of our existing framework (converting that framework to be compatible is another story I won't go into).  However, it appears I need to call the socket receive function on a loop (expected), but I can't use System.Threading (really annoying), and as far as I know, any Timer I set up on any xaml page won't survive past that page, so I'd have to create and link a timer to every page in the project, which seems horribly dirty.  I need a persistent timer.  There must be something I'm missing here... can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Have you seen the [`Windows.System.Threading` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.threading.aspx)?

Comment: I have not... reading up on it now... all this duplicated and moved functionality is making my head spin.  Thanks.

Comment: That did it, along with some help from DispatcherTimer!  Post an answer so I can mark it correct, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are equivalents to most of the functionality from the `System.Threading` namespace  in the [`Windows.System.Threading` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.threading.aspx)